# Android SDK file not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, adb

I am new to flutter and everything was working fine for me until I updated flutter today from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3 when I started to get this error I tried everything from configuring the adb manually and everything I could get on stack overflow. Can anybody help me with this error it will be a great help for me.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.870], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.3 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 4d7946a68d (4 days ago), 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
    • Engine revision 3459eb2436
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\san06\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-S, build-tools 30.0.3
    X Android SDK file not found: adb.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.74

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have accepted all android licenses too

```
D:\Flutter\flutter_udemy_first>flutter doctor --android-licenses
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Comment: what is the output of `which adb` on terminal?

Comment: D:\Flutter\flutter_udemy_first>which adb
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to uninstall and reinstall and it worked for me!

Comment: Please elaborate on what you uninstalled and reinstalled?